# Difference between ",' and ` in quoting

Tags: grammar, british-english, programming

I'm designing a template language that tries to adhere as closely as possible to english grammar and HTML syntax. For example, arrays are declared by appending an s to a word rather than prepending a symbol. Now in my favourite language PERL enclosing a phrase in "" means it will be interpolated and enclosing it in '' means it will left untouched. So

```
$name = 'dave'; print "hello $name"; print 'hello $name';
```

Will print

```
hello dave
hello $name
```

So my question is is this the right way around or should it be reversed? My understanding is in general writing using " means a direct quote and I'm not sure as sure about using ' to enclose a quotation but it seems to be used interchangeably with " in general writing. And of course whichever way I go a phrase like "Sorry $name, I can't do that" would need to be enclosed in " unless I go with the backtick for an untouched phrase like `I can't do that` but this is now invalid HTML. The general solution in programming seems to be using an escaping backslash like 'I can\'t do that' but that seems very ugly to my eyes and will no doubt take years off my life to implement. Just curious if any grammar nerds have an opinion on this.

Comment: This question doesn't have an answer as there's no way to closely adhere to English grammar on this issue since the grammar is different in different places, like in the UK, the grammar is to enclose quotes with a single quotation mark (') and quotes within quotes with double quotations marks ("), but like in the US, the grammar is the opposite. That's to say nothing of style guides that may supersede the local grammar. As for `, it's just a directional open-quote, ' being more common as it is directionless so can be used as a close-quote too, thus taking just one keyboard key instead of two.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman No, it's really not. In the UK it's double-quote first, containing single. That's what I was taught, and commonly encounter — which simply means *there is no rule.* Or possibly, the rule is *choose one method and be consistent.*